# How to change the color of a text in a button, where when the cursor is hovered over / clicks on the button, the of the text changes accordingly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried other examples from stackoverflow but none of which worked out for me (idk if i'm allowed to share them in the description)

```js
        var offerBTN = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
        var title = document.getElementsById("button_title");
        var subtitle = document.getElementsById("subtitle");

        offerBTN.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            title.style.color = "rgb(170, 170, 170)";
            subtitle.style.color = "rgb(170, 170, 170)";
        })
        offerBTN.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
            title.style.color = "rgb(170, 170, 170)";
            subtitle.style.color = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
        })
        offerBTN.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
            title.style.color = "rgb(200, 100, 100)";//unselected
            subtitle.style.color = "rgb(100, 200, 100)";
        })
        offerBTN.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
            title.style.color = "rgb(100, 200, 100)";
            subtitle.style.color = "rgb(100, 100, 200)";//selected
        })
```

```html
 <button class="button">
            <h3 id="button_title">Job Position 10 ></h3>
            <p id="subtitle">City, Country | Department | Keyword</p>
    </button>
```

Comment: What about using the `click` event listener?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify anywhere that you require doing this with Javascript.

If that is in fact the case, I'd suggest using CSS to achieve your desired result.

```css
button:hover #button_title,
button:hover #subtitle {
  color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
}

button:active #button_title {
  color: rgb(100, 200, 100);
}
button:active #subtitle {
  color: rgb(100, 100, 200);
}

// and so on...
```

```html
<button class="button">
    <h3 id="button_title">Job Position 10 ></h3>
    <p id="subtitle">City, Country | Department | Keyword</p>
</button>
```

Comment: heyy i didnt understand what you mean by i didnt specify using js, but ill try doing what you suggested much appreciated

Comment: You didn't mention in your question that you must solve this using javascript, so this answer solves your problem without using js. It is also more performant to use css over js. Only use js if it can't be solved with css, imo.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is having 2 mistakes -

1. You have mispelled `getElementById()` function. Its not getElementsById().
2. getElementsByClass() function returns array of target elements. So you cannot write directly `offerBTN.addEventListener()`.

Here is the correct code -

```js
var offerBTN = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
var title = document.getElementById("button_title");
var subtitle = document.getElementById("subtitle");

offerBTN[0].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  title.style.color = "rgb(170, 170, 170)";
  subtitle.style.color = "rgb(170, 170, 170)";
})
offerBTN[0].addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  title.style.color = "rgb(170, 170, 170)";
  subtitle.style.color = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
})
offerBTN[0].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  title.style.color = "rgb(200, 100, 100)"; //unselected
  subtitle.style.color = "rgb(100, 200, 100)";
})
offerBTN[0].addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  title.style.color = "rgb(100, 200, 100)";
  subtitle.style.color = "rgb(100, 100, 200)"; //selected
})
```

```html
<button class="button">
    <h3 id="button_title">Job Position 10 ></h3>
    <p id="subtitle">City, Country | Department | Keyword</p>
</button>
```

if you have a single button on which you want to do this thing then I would suggest to use `id` instead of `class`.

Comment: heyy much appreciated, may i ask why did you add [0] next to offerBTN ://

Comment: As I already mentioned, `getElementsByClass()` function returns an array. So you have to specify the index to get that array element.

Comment: if i have more than one button of the same type and behavior what should I do in this case?
 I tried writing it as var offerBTN = document.getElementByClassName("button"); but it didn't work

Comment: iterate over offerBTN array using for loop and then you write like this `offerBTN[i].addEventListener()`

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            offerBTN[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
                title.style.color = "rgb(170, 170, 170)";
                subtitle.style.color = "rgb(170, 170, 170)";
            })
        } //like this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just add some css like this:

```
.button:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: And if you only need to change the <p> tag color, maybe try something like:
.button p:hover { color: red; }

Comment: heyy, i have an h3 and a p in the button, so if i do what you told me the color of both the h3 and the p will be the same (i dont want them to be the same)

Comment: yea sorry I found it: 
.button:hover p{
  color: red;
}

Comment: When hovering over the button, only the p tags will be highlighted with the css ;)